# How can I make sure that the decorations are maintained?

Tags: build.gradle

The code now allows you to double-click the desired date on the calendar to set the alarm and adjust the schedule with the checkbox. When you finish your schedule, a small dot is stamped on the calendar as a decoration. However, this dot is not maintained and when you go to another screen, the dot disappears, and you have to click on the date of the calendar to see the decoration again. I hope this decoration stays. Please help me fix the code.

```
class PillFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var calendar: MaterialCalendarView
    lateinit var pillListAdapter: PillListAdapter
    lateinit var progress: ProgressBar
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var pillsList: ArrayList<PillListInfo> //서버에서 가져온 모든 알약 정보를 담은 리스트
    private lateinit var userId: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        UserApiClient.instance.me { user, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e(, , error)
            } else if (user != null) {
                userId = user.id.toString()
            }
        }
        requestPermission()
    }

   
    private fun requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext().applicationContext,
                    android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        requireActivity(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                    )
                ) {
                    
                    val intent: Intent =
                        Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).setData(
                            Uri.parse( + requireActivity().packageName)
                        )
                    startActivity(intent)
                    requireActivity().finish()
                } else {
                    
                    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
                        when (it) {
                            true -> {
                                Toast.makeText(context, , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                            false -> {
                                Toast.makeText(context, , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true)
                                requireActivity().finishAndRemoveTask()
                                exitProcess(0)
                            }
                        }
                    }.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pill, container, false)
        calendar = view.findViewById(R.id.cal_calendar)
        calendar.selectedDate = CalendarDay.today() 
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.re_pill_list)
        progress = view.findViewById(R.id.pr_loading)
        pillsList = ArrayList()
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // progress 초기화
        progress = view.findViewById(R.id.pr_loading)
        progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE 
        UserApiClient.instance.me { user, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e(, , error)
            } else if (user != null) {
                userId = user.id.toString()
                requestPillData(userId)
            }
        }

        setEvent()
        sendFCM()
    }

    
    private fun sendNotificationFCM(pillList: ArrayList<PillListInfo>) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { token ->
                Thread {
                    val todayPill = ArrayList<PillListInfo>()
                    pillList.forEach {
                        val year = it.calendarYear
                        val month = it.calendarMonth
                        val day = it.calendarDay

                        val today = CalendarDay.today()

                        if (year == today.year && month == today.month && day == today.day) {
                            todayPill.add(it)
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        var pillStr = __
                        todayPill.forEach {
                            pillStr += 
                        }

                        val fcm = SendNotfication()
                        if (todayPill.isNotEmpty()) {
                            fcm.sendTopicNotification(
                                token,
                                ,
                                
                            )
                        } else {
                            fcm.sendTopicNotification(
                                token,
                                ,
                                
                            )
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }.start()
            }
                .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? ->
                    Log.i(
                        
               )
                }
        }
    }

   
    private fun requestPillData(userId: String) {
        progress = requireView().findViewById(R.id.pr_loading)
        progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        
        val selectedDate = calendar.selectedDate
        val date = ${selectedDate?.year}${selectedDate?.month}${selectedDate?.day}

        MyRef.alarmRef.child(userId).child(date)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    
                    pillsList.clear()
                    for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val key = postSnapshot.key.toString()
                        val alarmname = postSnapshot.child().getValue(String::class.java)
                        val alarmhour = postSnapshot.child().getValue(Int::class.java)
                        val alarmminute = postSnapshot.child().getValue(Int::class.java)
                        val alarmYear = postSnapshot.child().getValue(Int::class.java)
                        val alarmMonth =
                            postSnapshot.child().getValue(Int::class.java)
                        val alarmDay = postSnapshot.child().getValue(Int::class.java)
                        val isChecked = postSnapshot.child().getValue(Boolean::class.java)
                        if (alarmname != null && alarmhour != null && alarmminute != null &&
                            alarmYear != null && alarmMonth != null && alarmDay != null && isChecked != null
                        ) {
                           
                            pillsList.add(
                                PillListInfo(
                                    key,
                                    alarmname,
                                    alarmhour,
                                    alarmminute,
                                    alarmYear,
                                    alarmMonth,
                                    alarmDay,
                                    isChecked
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i();


                    checkPillChecked()
                    comparePillData()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.e(, , databaseError.toException())
                }
            })

        
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            delay(2000)
            progress.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private fun sendFCM() {
        Thread {
            sleep(3000)
            sendNotificationFCM(pillsList)
        }.start()
    }

  
    private fun checkPillChecked() {
        pillsList.forEach {
            val itemYear = it.calendarYear
            val itemMonth = it.calendarMonth
            val itemDay = it.calendarDay
            val checked = it.checked

            val date = CalendarDay.from(itemYear, itemMonth, itemDay)
            if (checked) {
                val newDecorator = object : DayViewDecorator {
                    override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay?): Boolean {
                        return day == date
                    }

                    override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade?) {
                        view?.addSpan(DotSpan(5f, Color.BLUE))
                    }
                }

                // 이전에 추가된 장식이 있으면 제거
                decoratedDates[date]?.let { calendar.removeDecorator(it) }

                // 새로운 장식 추가
                calendar.addDecorator(newDecorator)
                decoratedDates[date] = newDecorator
            } else {
                // allSelected가 false일 때 장식 제거
                decoratedDates[date]?.let {
                    calendar.removeDecorator(it)
                    decoratedDates.remove(date)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var clickCount = 0
    var clickTime = 0L
    var selectedDate = 

    
    private fun setEvent() {
        calendar.setOnDateChangedListener { widget, date, selected ->
            if (calendar.selectedDate.toString() == selectedDate) {
                clickCount++
            } else {
                clickCount = 1
            }

            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (clickCount == 1) {
                clickTime = currentTime
                selectedDate = calendar.selectedDate.toString()
                comparePillData()
                requestPillData(userId)

            } else if (clickCount >= 2 && selectedDate == calendar.selectedDate.toString()) {
                val diff = currentTime - clickTime
                if (diff < 1000) {
                    clickCount = 0
                    //val selectedDate = 
                    val i = Intent(requireContext(), AddAlarmActivity::class.java)
                    i.putExtra(, date.year)
                    i.putExtra(, date.month)
                    i.putExtra(, date.day)
                    startActivity(i)
                } else {
                    clickCount = 0
                    clickTime = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }


    val decoratedDates = HashMap<CalendarDay, DayViewDecorator>()

    
    private fun comparePillData() {
        val selectedDate = calendar.selectedDate
        val selectedYear = selectedDate?.year
        val selectedMonth = selectedDate?.month
        val selectedDay = selectedDate?.day

        val selectedPillList = ArrayList<PillListInfo>()
        for (i in pillsList) {
            if (i.calendarYear == selectedYear && i.calendarMonth == selectedMonth && i.calendarDay == selectedDay) {
                selectedPillList.add(i)
            }
        }
        pillListAdapter =
            PillListAdapter(selectedPillList, object : PillListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(data: PillListInfo, position: Int) {
                    
                    pillsList.forEach {
                        if (it.mediName == data.mediName) {
                            it.checked = data.checked
                        }
                    }
                    pillsList.reverse()
                    val key = data.key

                    val pill = Pill(
                        data.key,
                        data.mediName,
                        data.hour,
                        data.minute,
                        data.calendarYear,
                        data.calendarMonth,
                        data.calendarDay,
                        data.checked
                    )
                    MyRef.alarmRef.child(userId)
                        .child{${data.calendarYear}${data.calendarMonth}${data.calendarDay})
                        .child(key).setValue(pill)

                    var isAllChecked = true
                    
                    selectedPillList.forEach {
                        if (it.checked == false) {
                            isAllChecked = false
                        }
                    }
                    
                    val date =
                        CalendarDay.from(data.calendarYear, data.calendarMonth, data.calendarDay)

                    
                    if (isAllChecked == true) {
                        
                        val newDecorator = object : DayViewDecorator {
                            override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay?): Boolean {
                                return day == date
                            }

                            override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade?) {
                                view?.addSpan(DotSpan(5f, Color.BLUE))
                            }
                        }
                        
                        decoratedDates[date]?.let { calendar.removeDecorator(it) }
                        
                        calendar.addDecorator(newDecorator)
                        decoratedDates[date] = newDecorator
                    } else {
                        
                        decoratedDates[date]?.let {
                            calendar.removeDecorator(it)
                            decoratedDates.remove(date)
                        }
                    }
                }

                
                override fun onItemDelete(data: PillListInfo, position: Int) {
                    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                    dialog.setTitle()
                    dialog.setMessage(${data.mediName}?)
                    dialog.setPositiveButton() { dialog, which ->
                        val key = data.key
                        
                        MyRef.alarmRef.child(userId)
                            .child()
                            .child(key).removeValue()
                        selectedPillList.removeAt(position)
                        pillListAdapter.updateItems(selectedPillList)
                        pillsList.remove(data)

                        
                        if (selectedPillList.isEmpty()) {
                            val date = CalendarDay.from(
                                data.calendarYear,
                                data.calendarMonth,
                                data.calendarDay
                            )
                            decoratedDates[date]?.let {
                                calendar.removeDecorator(it)
                                decoratedDates.remove(date)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    dialog.setNegativeButton() { dialog, which ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    dialog.show()
                }
            })
        
        recyclerView.adapter = pillListAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (::pillsList.isInitialized) {
            UserApiClient.instance.me { user, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e(, , error)
                } else if (user != null) {
                    userId = user.id.toString()
                    requestPillData(userId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```